# Has anyone tried exporting an SDE Geodatabase into ArcPad before?

Tags: gps, gis, arcgis

We recently upgraded a to an ArcSDE Server based Geodatabase. I want to be able to sync straight to my server with data from my field data from GPS. I don't have Pathfinder or Terrasync, just ArcPad.

I am having trouble figuring out how to get my feature classes on to my Trimble GPS so I can field edit.

Does anyone have any experience with this combination of hardware and software?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ArcPad 10.2, here is the link for [ArcPad help library](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcpad/10.2/app/) click on Data Management folder then select ArcPad Data Manager for ArcGIS folder then click on The ArcPad Data Manager toolbar in ArcGIS folder and it will show how to get data from/to your ArcPad.